# Como integrar uma Class Library a um Database Project no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, class-library

Olá, estou criando uma solução no Visual Studio em que eu gostaria de separar todas as camadas da aplicação em projetos para ter uma estruturação mais bem definida. A minha solução até então está assim:

```
Solution
| - Database (Database Project)
    | - Tables
        | - ...
| - Model (Class Library)
    | - ...
| - Kernel (Class Library)
    | - Interfaces
        | - IIndexable
        | - IStatusControlable
        | - ITraceableCreation
        | - ITraceableUpdate
```

A ideia dessa estrutura é que eu possa definir interfaces de implementações que eu possa forçar a implementação das mesmas nos models ou em qualquer outra estrutura que se baseie nas regras de negócio (Kernel). Partindo disso tenho a implementação dessas interfaces:

```
interface IIndexable 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
interface IStatusControlable 
{
    string Status { get; set; }
}
interface ITraceableCreation 
{
    DateTime CriadoEm { get; set; }
}
interface ITraceableUpdate 
{
    DateTime AtualizadoEm { get; set; }
}
```

O problema é que, na hora de criar o projeto de base de dados, eu devo também forçar a implementação dos campos para as tabelas e afins, por exemplo se eu tivesse uma classe `Usuario`, a implementação da mesma teria essa estrutura

```
class Usuario: IIndexable, IStatusControlable, ITraceableCreation, ITraceableUpdate 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime CriadoEm { get; set; }
    public DateTime AtualizadoEm { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

E a sua implementação dentro da base de dados refletiria nisso:

```
create table Usuario (
    Id int not null identity primary key,
    Status nchar(1) not null default 'a',
    CriadoEm datetime not null default getdate(),
    AtualizadoEm datetime not null default getdate(),
    Login nvarchar(50) not null unique,
    Senha nvarchar(100) not null,
    Email nvarchar(100) not null unique
);
```

O problema é que, caso o projeto esteja em andamento de desenvolvimento e surja mais alguma variação, por exemplo, foi definido que a interface `IStatusControlable` agora será controlada usando um enum interno assim:

```
enum StatusControlableEnum { 
    Ativo, Inativo, Removido, Protegido, Estatico 
}
interface IStatusControlable 
{
    StatusControlableEnum Status { get; set; }
}
```

O que faz com que o tipo da propriedade `Status` se torne `StatusControlableEnum` e todas as estruturas que utilizam essa interface tenham que mudar.

O problema é que essa alteração não é refletida diretamente ao projeto de base de dados, fazendo com que todas as referências de construção das tabelas que representam persistências que contém aquela interface tenham que ser geridas manualmente.

Existe alguma forma de usar interfaces ou ao menos indicar a implementação incorreta de alguma interface para uma tabela definida em um `Database Project` no Visual Studio?